# Obtener la cantidad de comentarios de cada publicación

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una sentencia **sql** para sacar la cantidad de comentario de cada publicación, pero solo me saca 1 cuando en realidad hay 5 comentarios en esa publicación.

**Sentencia SQL:**

```
<?php

$post = (int)$post;

// Sacar la cantidad de comentario por producto
$stmt = $conexion->query("SELECT id_comment, COUNT(id_comment) AS cantidad FROM comment WHERE product_id = $post GROUP BY id_comment");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // cantidad de comentarios
    $cantidad = $row['cantidad'];

}
```

**Esta es la forma de la tabla comment de comentarios**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Me muestra 1 comentario cuando en verdad hay 5 comentarios en esa publicación**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que puedan ayudarme, un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas sumando la columna incorrecta

- La columna `comment_id` parece ser la llave primaria de tu tabla `comment` por lo tanto ese valor será único
- La columna que debes usar para el conteo es la que identifica al usuario que realizó dicho comentario en este caso `user_id`, ya que esta llave foránea es la que se podrá repetir varias veces en razón de la misma cantidad de veces que un usuario deja un comentario

Te comento que debería ser así:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS cantidad 
FROM comment 
WHERE product_id = $post;
```

- Dado tu enunciado de obtener la cantidad, entonces:

  - No necesitas otras columnas en tu `SELECT`
  - No necesitas agrupar por que solo obtendrás la cantidad numérica del total